# Canon Maxify MB5020 scan above 600dpi

Tags: printer, resolution, scanner

My [Canon Maxify MB5020](http://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/printers-all-in-ones/small-office-home-office-all-in-one-inkjet-printers/maxify-mb5020)  specification indicates max optical scan as 1200 dpi or up to 19,200 interpolated:

> [image: specifications]

However, with drivers installed I cannot select above 600 dpi:

[image: scanner]

1200 x 1200 dpi optical should be a selectable option, referring to the optical resolution of the CCD cell and mechanical stepping of the motor drive.

Is there something I'm missing regarding configuration; or, the specification itself?

How can I scan at 1200 dpi?

Comment: What is your operating system and what software are you using to scan?  You might be running into a filesize limit.  The raw size of a 1200x1200 letter size color scan is over 400MB, which may exceed some software limits.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.5 - Photoshop CC, import from device, using [drivers from Canon](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/small_office_home_office_inkjet_printers/maxify_mb5020)

Comment: Try reducing the scan window to a much smaller size as a test and see if it will let you go to 1200x1200.

Comment: Good idea, but no luck - set to 1" on a variety of different formats, and it does not increase past 600 dpi.

Comment: What is the scanner interface in the picture (Canon scanning software, Photoshop using a TWAIN interface, etc.)?  Is there another scanner interface you can try?

Comment: This is a long shot, but something to check.  The software that came with my Epson scanner had different "modes".  The modes were intended to simplify your life (but fail miserably at that).  The modes limit the available settings to what is supposedly relevant for that mode.  You needed to go to a particular mode to access the full range of capabilities.  I tossed that bundled software, but it was called something like "artist" mode, or "advanced", or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will apply to you case, but I was having the same trouble with the Canon LiDE220 with the [Canon driver](https://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/scanners/photo_scanners/canoscan_lide220#DriversAndSoftware) and OS X El Capitan using Image Capture.

For me, Image Capture let me type values for the resolution not available in the dropdown. From your screenshot the *600* is it highlighted and you might be able to simply type *1200* and then scan.